# Filling an array with fillers in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want the user to first type a code (e.g. fkuk3463kj)
The array is limited to 20.
The rest must be filled with fillers. 
Which filler the customer will use (e.g. #, t, z,7,_,0) is his own choice and he will asked to define it at the beginning right after the question for the code.

(hint: afterwards (or if possible directly) I have to decide (to complete the wish of customer) whether the filler has to be at the beginning or at the end.
(for example: fkuk3463kj########## or ##########fkuk3463kj)

Now I don't know how to implement this. I know, that it's not that difficult, but I don't get it! All my tryings were not really succesful.

Could anybody help me? This would be perfect! 
And many thx in advance!

```
Console.WriteLine("Please type in your company number!");
string companyNr = Console.ReadLine();
string[] CNr = new string[companyNr.Length];
Console.WriteLine("Type a filler");
string filler= Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
string[] fill = new string[filler.Length];

.
.
.
.
.
```

(please pardon my english...)

Comment: What do you want to do with: `string[] CNr = new string[companyNr.Length];`?

Comment: Basically, your on the right track. You just need to store the number needed filler chars in an `int`. When you have this number, you'll have various way to create a string with the right amount of filler chars.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < companyNr.Length; i++)
                {
                    LFSNr[i] = Convert.ToString(companyNr[i]);
                    Console.Write(CNr[i]);
                }

Comment: that was just for testing the array

Comment: <<Basically, your on the right track. You just need to store the number needed filler chars in an int. When you have this number, you'll have various way to create a string with the right amount of filler chars. >>


omg! that is one of those things, that didn't come in my mind today!

Comment: Well, I am glad that it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! One thing I wanna mention: Later I have to change this code to C/AL (Microsoft Dynamics Nav). So I would like to keep the use of the Visual Basic Library as small as possible.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, you're working with `string`:

```
 // Trim: let's trim off leading and trailing spaces: "  abc " -> "abc"
 string companyNr = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
```

which you want to `Pad` with some `char` up to the length `length` (`20` in your case):

```
 int length = 20;

 string filler = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
 // padding character: either provided by user or default one (#) 
 char pad = string.IsNullOrEmpty(filler) ? '#' : filler[0];

 // shall we pad left: "abc" -> "##abc" or right: "abc" -> "abc##"
 // I have to decide (to complete the wish of customer) 
 //TODO: whether the filler has to be at the beginning or at the end
 bool leftPad = true;

 string result = leftPad
   ? companyNr.PadLeft(length, pad) 
   : companyNr.PadRight(length, pad);

 // in case you want a char array
 char[] array = result.ToCharArray();
 // in case you want a string array
 string[] strArray = result.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are getting strings as an input you can use string padding. Look here: [Padding Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I know it's an MSDN page and that *should* be safe, but please add more detail to your post just in case the link changes.

Comment: @dckuehn Apart from the chance on the content of the link changing Mats should add the relevant information from that page here, or at least an example of how to use this in OPs scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can write some method (or extension method):

```
string AppendString(string str, int count, char filler, bool fromStart)
{
    return fromStart ? str.PadLeft(count, filler) : str.PadRight(count, filler);
}
```

Comment: I thought about a method too, but couldn't really get into it.

Comment: @4711, accept the answer that works and is the best for you

Comment: Yes, I have to test it tomorrow. 
I have to take the one which I can easily change into the language C/AL.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code should work for you.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please type in your company number!");
string companyNr = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Type a filler");
string filler= Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

string fill = companyNr.PadLeft(20,filler);
// or use string fill = companyNr.PadRight(20,filler);
```

Welcome to StackOverflow. I am also a beginner :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int fixedLength = 20;
string mockupInput = "bladjiea";
string filler = "-";
While(mockupInput.Length < fixedLength)
{
    mockupInput += filler;
}
```

This is easy beginner code that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make this a contest on who will write most beautiful code:

I'll start with the most trivial, brute method XD.

If you have the number:

```
int fillLength = 20 - companyNr.Length; //for example, 20 chars total.
```

You can fill a `StringBuilder` in a loop:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder()
for (int c = 0; c < fillLength; c++)
    sb.Append(filler);

string result = companyNr  + sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: It is. And as for this problem, there are at least as many solutions.

Comment: Whats wrong with `companyNr.PadLeft(20, filler);`? I think it's beautiful. Shorter, more readable..

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: I didn't need to win, although yours seems to qualify ;) I was just trying to point out that there are many options to solve this problem (and many different answers will be given). Which I think is a good thing, because, given OP's question, OP seems to be relatively new to the framework.

Comment: Stefan, so it is beautiful in my eyes! Thanks a lot!